# How to delete take certain channels and categories and delete them? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want that when a user writes a command, the bot deletes certain channels with certain names, but I can't succeed.

**Error:**

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'get_category'
```

**Code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def verification_channels_delete(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Удаляю категории и каналы для верефикации...')

    category1 = await ctx.message.guild.get_category('Verification')
    category2 = await ctx.message.guild.get_category("Chat")

    await category1.delete()
    await category2.delete()

    channel1 = await ctx.message.guild.get_text_channel("Verification")
    channel2 = await ctx.message.guild.get_text_channel("Chat")

    await channel1.delete()
    await channel2.delete()

    await ctx.send('Я удалил все каналы для верефикации!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get channel, category, or anything else **by name** you should use `discord_utils` for it:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@client.command()
async def verification_channels_delete(ctx):
    category1 = get(ctx.guild.categories, name = "Verification")
    category2 = get(ctx.guild.categories, name = "Chat")
    await category1.delete()
    await category2.delete()

    channel1 = get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name = "verification")
    channel2 = get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name = "chat")
    await channel1.delete()
    await channel2.delete()
```